# Working of a Diode Ring

Tags: rf, diodes

I am trying to understand the working of a Diode ring circuit from this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=junuEwmQVQ8&t=675s)

I find difficulty in understanding how the circuit works.

How is the voltage at the point marked below is equal to ground?

[image: Diode ring circuit]

When the RF is 10 MHz and the Local Oscillator is also 10MHz, then only the current flows, right?

Can someone explain that circuit and how that marked terminal is taken as ground reference while he explains that circuit?

And it would be great if someone could help with some frequency examples along with the working of the circuit

Comment: Could you please explain the entire thing with answers to my questions?

Comment: @StefanWyss no, that's wrong. This isn't a rectifier, this is a mixer. So, yes, that is intentional. No, that's not a short. There's two diodes in forward bias in between. Newbie's circuit is correct!

Comment: @MarcusMüller .. Could you please explain on the working in simple terms

Comment: Sorry, no, your question is simply too broad. What about you completely ignore the ground reference for now. Does that circuit make sense then? Does [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_mixer#Diode) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this circuit, every diode acts similarly to a switch. Diodes are used because they switch fast (ten million switches per second). In the simple model, the switch is either open or closed.
The local oscillator determines switch timing: on one half cycle both diodes are **open**, on the other half-cycle both diodes are **closed**.

The circuits below are a slight modification of the OP's diagram. Works similarly, but may be easier to see the functional operation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNuZvq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

 When L2 and L3 are equal, and D1 matches D2, the local oscillator signal (which is switching diodes D1 & D2 on and off) doesn't disturb the signal....it is a balanced bridge. If balanced, no local oscillator signal flows through **Rload**. During the half-cycle when the two diode switches are closed (on), **Vsig** current can flow through **Rload**. Half of this current could flow through L2,D1, and half through L3,D2. During the half-cycle when the two diode switches are open (off), no **Vsig** current can flow.

For one-half cycle, **Rload** is connected to **Vsignal**, and for the other half cycle, **Rload** is disconnected from **Vsignal**. Notice that no ground is shown. Ground could be placed at the junction of **L2,L3,Rload**, or ground could be placed at the junction of **D1,D2,Vsig**...the only difference is in the phase of the output signal across(through) **Rload**. In the OP's diagram, ground is placed at the junction of **L2,L3,Rload**.

If the frequencies of **Vlocal osc** and **Vsignal** are the same, then the average voltage (or current) in **Rload** has a DC component which depends on the phase relationship between **Vlocal oscl** and **Vsignal**. This circuit can be used as a phase detector.
If the frequencies of **Vlocal osc** and **Vsignal** differ, then the voltage (or current) in **Rload** has a number of component parts, some of the major ones being:

- Vsignal frequency
- Vsignal + Vlocal osc frequency
- Vsignal - Vlocal osc frequency

[image: mixer output across Rload]This waveform example shows the output voltage or current at **Rload** where **Vlocal osc** frequency differs from **Vsig** frequency. One-and-a-half cycles of the low-frequency difference (Vsignal - Vlocal osc) can be clearly seen.
This simplified mixer is only half-balanced. This means that very little of the switching signal of **Vlocal osc** appears in **Rload**. There are variations of switched diodes that short **Vsignal** for one-half cycle, instead of this variation where **Vsignal** is opened (off) for one-half cycle.

 A full-bridge of 4-diodes conducts signal current on *both half-cycles*, but reverses **Rload** current direction on alternate half-cycles of **Vlocal osc**. This version can be *fully-balanced*, where **Rload** is isolated from both **Vlocal osc** and from **Vsig**, and sees mostly the two mixing frequency components **Vsig + Vlocal osc** and **Vsig - Vlocal osc**:
[image: double-balanced mixer output]